# Spree::Config is the same of Application::Config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I see very often this config on spree models, what this if for? is the same if i call Application::Config or Rails::Config?

what mean this Config?

is some kind of config callback?

thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are completely different things. It's quite well documented [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/preferences.html).